# Creating widget for product website

Tags: facebook, video, twitter, youtube, widget

I am not sure if i am asking this correctly or the terminology are correct but it is according to my understanding. I am developing a video hosting website and i want my users to share those videos to social network and may be embed them on their website. What i like is when they share those videos, in their feed they should be able to play those videos without leaving the their current social networks, its just like youtube, when i share videos on twitter or facebook i can play youtube videos from there without opening the youtube site. Where should i look into to build such widget ? How do i create such?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the pages the videos reside on that are shared contain valid and correct OpenGraph tags.

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/video.other/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices